# VBS message if Value is too long or too short

Tags: vbscript

I have a variable called JobNumberTxtBx

the input is established with this:

```
input type="text" name="JobNumberTxtBx" size="6" maxLength="6" value=""
```

I am trying to call up an error box if the value entered has less than 6 digits or more than 7 digits.

I have tried:

```
If JobNumberTxtBx.Value < 6 Or JobNumberTxtBx.Value > 7 Then
    MsgBox "Please type six digits for Job Number"
End If
```

But it does not work.

Any ideas will be appreciated. unfortunately, I am not skilled or knowledgeable, I am trying hard to piece this together from online sources. I realise that I have limited the users entry length to 6 digits so writing Value > 7 is redundant but i wanted this just in case i change that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.Value` is a *string*, and thus `<` or `>` operators will be comparing alphabetically.

To get the *length*, you need to use `Len(string)`.

```
If Len(JobNumberTxtBx.Value) < 6 Or Len(JobNumberTxtBx.Value)  > 7 Then
    MsgBox "Please type six digits for Job Number"
End If
```

Comment: Does `.length` work with VBScript? It's a while since I've done DOM work with VBScript but wouldn't it be `If Len(JobNumberTxtBx.Value) < 6 Or Len(JobNumberTxtBx.Value) > 7 Then`? I'm sure `.length` syntax is JavaScript.

Comment: Oh jeez, good catch! I've been doing so much VB.Net that I've grown completely accustomed to just doing `.length`. I'll edit my answer, thanks!

Comment: Thank you that makes sense, I will try it out.

Comment: Hey great that works!  Thanks Santi and Lankimart for the script catch. How do I stop the run of the script so the user must return to the interface before the script runs and completes?